# SandboxViolation error when installing statsmodels with easy_install

Tags: python, fedora, easy-install, statsmodels

I tried to install `statsmodels` Python library on a Fedora 19 system. I used `easy_install` as follows:

```
easy_install -U statsmodels
```

But I get the following error while installing:

```
error: SandboxViolation: os.open('/root/.matplotlib/tmpvjSAwn', 131266, 384) {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the setup.py in source, add

```
os.environ["MPLCONFIGDIR"] = "."
```

after import os
Then I got the following error when I called the

```
python setup.py install
```

from the statsmodels directory.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 465, in <module>
    check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
  File "setup.py", line 124, in check_dependency_versions
    raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")
```

pasty was missing in the system. So only thing I had to do was installing pasty. using

```
easy_install --upgrade patsy
```

then I could install statsmodels from the source in the normal way.